# Support for cursor on pseudo elements in IE

Tags: css, less

I was wondering if IE supports the below format?

LESS code :

```
.a:not(.b) {
  .c:hover:before {
    cursor:nwse-resize;
  }
}
```

The same works fine with chrome and firefox

```css
.c:before {
  content: "Hover me"
}

.a:not(.b) .c:hover:before {
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p class="c">
    Some text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="a b">
  <p class="c">
    Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

The expectation is that the browser should show an 'nwse' cursor when the conditions are met.

Works fine with chrome and firefox but not with IE.

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot

Comment: @Utkanos I have tried it and it does not work, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or IE does not support it.

The CSS seems to be present when the see the developer tools

Comment: Which version of IE? The most recent?

Comment: @JoeClay Yes the latest version of IE

Comment: @Pete I'm afraid the scenario is slightly more complex here, I am talking about the :not() pseudo class in combination with :hover and :before, I know that :not() is supported in IE, but I am not sure if the :hover and :before inside the :not() is supported, and I could not find any relevant documentation for the same.

Comment: @Pete I'm sorry to have mentioned it as CSS, I am actually using LESS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why your specific code it's not working is not about `:not` or `:hover` or `:before`. It's about `cursor` on `pseudo-elements` in IE.

You can apply other styles to the `before` but not cursor which is not supported in IE ( cursor on pseudo elements ).

To achieve the result you want ( cursor on before ) you can make something like this. See below

```css
.c:before {
  content: "Hover me";
  pointer-events: auto;   
}
.a:not(.b) .c {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p class="c">
    Some text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="a b">
  <p class="c">
    Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

Cursor styles ( like other styles ) are inherited by the children ( `:before` in this case ) from the parent ( `.a:not(.b) .c` in this case ). So add the pointer to the parent but also add `pointer-events: none;` which removes any actions like `:hover` or `:focus` etc. Then on the child override the `pointer-events` to auto.

This is NOT a perfect solution as it disables other interactions on the parent but in this specific case, it gets the job done.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @DwarakeshPallagolla glad i could help ! cheers :D